# Is it OK if I have some high leverage points in my experimental plots and they weren't outliers?

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, leverage

[image: here is normal probability plot versus internally studentized residuals]I've analyzed effects of temperature and sample thickness on drying process via response surface methodology. I've faced to four high leverage points (my four axial runs) that stick together on normal probability plot. these points aren't the outlier (on residual versus run plot).

Comment: Why would you care if the points have high leverage if they don't have high Cook's distance?

Comment: Labelling the axes might help.

Comment: so, that's not a problem in my data if I have some high leverage points that aren't outliers and don't have high Cook's Distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a high leverage point isn't an outlier doesn't mean all is well.

A single sufficiently influential point can pull the line essentially right through it (so its residual is 0).

A pair of influential points can easily make each other's externally studentized residuals zero / nearly zero.

So you can have a few points that behave as if they're from a completely different relationship from that you see in (say) 99% of the data, but  they're sufficiently influential, they will have small residuals and even their studentized *deleted* residuals (/externally studentized residuals) can be small.

This can happen with Cooks Distance (and a variety of other measures of influence) -- the effect of another outlier can make Cook's distance look fine for both.

If you remove all the influential points - as Michael suggests in comments - and the line is little changed, then there should be little to worry about.

Comment: This is true but let's say the slope of the regression line is not changed much when the influential point(s) are left out it doesn't have much effect to include them and it doesn't

Comment: @Michael Yes, that's a good point; if all the influential points (I believe OP mentioned there were four) are together deleted with little effect, there's  no harm in including them (and likely a considerable benefit in estimated variance of coefficients)